# Git - Finding a file with its offset

Tags: git, git-clone, inflate

I'm trying to clone a remote Git repo.

I've done it before without any issues, but on this project, I get the error

> fatal: pack has bad object at offset 289293315: inflate returned -5
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

How can I find which file is causing the error? I tried `git show :289293315`

But it's apparently not an index :

> fatal: Path '289293315' does not exist (neither on disk nor in the index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in a *pack file*.  A pack file contains many individual Git objects, all mushed together and [delta-compressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding).

To find the bad pack file, look in the `.git/objects/pack` directory, which will contain one or more `.pack` files and corresponding `.idx` files.  You can, for instance, run `git index-pack -v` on each `.pack` file, to look for issues.  That's what is happening now (without the `-v`).

You can also use `git unpack-objects -r` after moving the bad `.pack` file out of the repository itself, to attempt to recover whatever good objects remain.  However, your best bet is probably to find a good clone of the repository.  Meanwhile you should figure out why your existing pack file went bad:  Was something corrupting files?  Is your storage device failing?